# How do I add an on click pop-up window to an iText generated PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Basically, I want a built in pop-up window to appear in the PDF document when clicking on a certain Chunk element.

Apparently this is possible, but I have had a bad luck of finding a solution for it. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need the `setAction()` method and define an action. I know this is only half an answer, but then again, you've posted only half a question. To answer the second half of your question, we'd need to know what type of pop-up you want. Do you want an actual Pop-Up annotation (as described in Chapter 7 of "iText in Action - Second Edition") or is a JavaScript alert sufficient? What is the purpose of the "popup window"? Note that the PDF and AcroJS references talk about concepts such as popup annotations, alert-boxes, etc..., but the concept of a "popup window" isn't defined. You'll need to be more specific using PDF or AcroJS terminology.